# How fast is The Orville?

Tags: the-orville

What is the top speed of The Orville (or at least the fastest we've ever seen it travel) relative to the speed of light? (so non-fictional units)
How long would it take to travel across the galaxy?

Accepted sources would be dialogue within the TV show, any kind of background promotional material, or comments made by the show's creators.

Comment: [It goes 30 speed](https://imgur.com/gallery/E1YRsXQ)

Comment: It travels at the speed of plot.

Comment: [Very fast indeed](http://vignette2.wikia.nocookie.net/steven-universe/images/1/1d/Spaceballs-ludicrous-speed-o.gif/revision/latest?cb=20150812152815)

Comment: Trying to protect your own turf, I see, Mr. Cochrane.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In the episode "Pria", while touring the engine room, Ed tells her that the Orville can travel in excess of ten light years per hour (87,600 times the speed of light, as mentioned below), which is likely an upper limit. I haven't seen any reference yet to a standard crusing speed though.

Assuming the Milky Way Galaxy is ~100,000 light years in diameter, at their top speed, they could cross it in 10,000 hours or about 416 days.

Comment: Which is 100 times faster than the USS Voyager.

Comment: Which means that it's capable of traveling at 87,600 times the speed of light (warp 44), enabling it to complete the Voyager's journey in slightly less than a year.

Comment: @Valorum Warp 44 on what scale?

Comment: @JAB - The original TOS scale, not the TNG scale. On the TNG scale it would be something like warp 9.9999(ish)

Comment: In the New Warp Scale, it's (ish) all the way down. I wish they had retained a more linear scale...